# Wrong place of file in solution explorer

Tags: solution-explorer, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

When adding a file to Visual Studio, it's not in the right place in the Solution Explorer: It is at the root of the project. Bug is only in the solution explorer, it is in the right directory when checking with windows's explorer.
It happens randomly, not always.
Restarting VS does nothing, unloading and reloading project too. I have to regenerate the solution (with Premake)
Bug only happen with premake generated solutions

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

So, how to get the file back to his right place ?
My version of VS:
[image: VS2017 Community 15.2 (26430.15)]